# create php code for non exist hotmail emails

Tags: php, hotmail

I want to create hotmail email .
but i want a script that show me if email exist or not ,
thats mean I put list of emails and the result will be like ,
example :

```
jone123@hotmail.com : exist
jone1233@hotmail.com : doesn't exist
```

any ideas please ?

Comment: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6650-PHP-Check-if-an-e-mail-is-valid-using-SMTP.html

Comment: SO is for specific coding issues, this is too broad as is. Have you tried something?

Comment: no I didn't try any thing 
and I didn't know how to search for this sorry about that

Comment: I doubt you'll find much. I would hope no email providers would just give access to their DBs to anyone. Think what a spammer could do with this technology.. You could try navigating around hotmail/live docs.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to use external APIs to achieve this functionality.
You could try https://emailhunter.co/api

Comment: Thank you  for answering me but this will not work for me .
I want to put a list of emails not find a specific email

Comment: @codezero:  If you can check one, why can't you repeatedly check a list?  Aren't you a programmer?